# Formatting php into html table correctly

Tags: php, html-table

I have a php array that contains information from my database `$name[] = $row['name']`. There are also about 3 other rows that container `email`, `age`, and `screen-resolution`.

### I am trying to neatly assemle this into a table that looks like:

`name`----------`email`----------`age`----------`screen-res`

`name1`---------`email1`--------`age1`---------`res1`

`name2`---------`email2`--------`age2`---------`res2`

### However mine currently looks like this:

`name`----------`email`----------`age`----------`screen-res`

`name1`---------`name2`----------`name3`------`name4`---------`name5`------`name6`-------`name7`------`name8`

`email1`---------`email2`----------`email3`------`email`---------`email5`------`email6`-------`email7`

### My Code

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Screen-Res</th>
  </tr>
  <?php
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($name as $nameVal) {
        echo "<td>$nameVal</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($email as $emailVal) {
        echo "<td>$emailVal</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($age as $ageVal) {
        echo "<td>$ageVal</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($screen-res as $screen-resVal) {
        echo "<td>$screen-resVal</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
  ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forming your tables incorrectly. You your table to look something like this. The good thing is you only need one array for all your data

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Screen-Res</th>
  </tr>
  <?php

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['nameVal']."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$row['emailVal']."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$row['ageVal']."</td>";

        echo "<td>".$row['screen-resVal']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
    }

  ?>
</table>
```